# How to join data tables in R (inner,outer,left,right)?

Tags: r, join, data.table, bigdata

This is a replication of a previous post ([How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)), using `data.table()` rather than `data.frame()`.

Suppose I have two data tables:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(CustomerID=c(1:6),Product=c(rep("Toaster",3),rep("Radio",3)))
dt2 = data.table(CustomerID=c(2,4,6),State=c(rep("Alabama",2),rep("Ohio",1)))            

dt1
   CustomerID Product
1:          1 Toaster
2:          2 Toaster
3:          3 Toaster
4:          4   Radio
5:          5   Radio
6:          6   Radio
dt2
   CustomerID   State
1:          2 Alabama
2:          4 Alabama
3:          6    Ohio

setkey(dt1,CustomerID)
setkey(dt2, CustomerID)
```

The default using `merge()` on a `data.table` is a right join. What's the syntax for the others?

```
#Outer join:

#Right outer (data.table default): 
dtro <- merge(dt1,dt2); dtro 

   CustomerID Product   State
1:          2 Toaster Alabama
2:          4   Radio Alabama
3:          6   Radio    Ohio

#Left outer:

#Cross join:
```

Comment: I like the way this question moreso than the one @mnel linked to, but I agree it is a duplicate

Comment: `merge.data.table` takes the same `all.x` and `all.y` `all` arguments as `merge.data.frame`, so the accepted answer in the data.frame question will be correct here too.